# Unable to delete custom table view cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

In one of my ViewControllers, I added a tableview as a subview.

In this tableView I made implemented custom table view cells.

So, how  to delete the custom Table View Cell from tableView, when we press the delete button.

Can anyone help me out..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) 
     {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.itemTable removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]    withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
}
```